# how to check if an array contains a specific item

Tags: typescript

The below code gives the following error on

```
"[i]" in "if (i == ingredients[i])"
```

error:

> element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not
>   of type 'number'

code:

```
    let ingredients = ["ham","onion","tomato"];
    let sandwichhas = function(ingredients:string[]){
        for(let i of ingredients){
            if (i == ingredients[i]){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (snd("tomato") && snd("onion")){
      console.log("Sandwich has tomatos and onions")
    }else {
       console.log("Sandwich has no tomatos and onions")
    }
```

And in the if statement below there's an error saying:

> Argument of type '"tomato"' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'string[]'.
>
> Argument of type '"onion"' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'string[]'.

What is the workaround for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: The argument to the function should either be `ingredients:string` (for a single ingredient) or `...ingredients:string[]` (for multiple ingredients) if you want to call it as shown in your question.

Comment: https://dotlyapidev.herokuapp.com/23ruxzYYv

Comment: http://localhost:4040/HRzStGLB_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you modify your code to the following:

```
let ingredients = ["ham", "onion", "tomato"];
let snd = function (item) {
    for (let i = 0; i <= ingredients.length; i++) {

        if (item === ingredients[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

if (snd("tomato") && snd("onion")) {
    console.log("Sandwich has tomatos and onions")
} else {
    console.log("Sandwich has no tomatos and onions")
}
```

The function argument was set to ingredient, instead of a string parameter that you pass, such as "tomato" and "onion". They are of type "string", it is ingredient[], an array fro now. i in the iteration was used mistakenly also.

Comment: Would it not be easier to use `ingredients.some(....)` to do the filtering?

Comment: Yes, but the OP is looking to fix his code as it is. array methods are in the next chapter, I think

Comment: Fair enough! All is well